# Why doesn't ReactiveVar have a equals method?

Tags: meteor

I see the benefits with using `Session.equals('key', 'someValue')` in favor of `Session.get('key') == 'someValue'`, but shouldn't the same apply to `ReactiveVar`? Why doesn't it have a `equals` method?

A comment in the package says:

> This class is extremely basic right now, but the idea is to evolve 
>   it into the ReactiveVar of Geoff's Lickable Forms proposal.

Is it simply not yet implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-var/reactive-var.js), you'll see it isn't currently implemented. Interestingly, you can pass in a custom `equalsFunc` when you create the instance, although it's currently only used for dependency tracking.

It's possible it was tricky to get right, so `equals` was skipped temporarily. For now if you want to add it yourself, you could patch `ReactiveVar` with something like:

```js
_.defaults(ReactiveVar.prototype, {
  equals: function(value) {
    return _.isEqual(this.get(), value);
  }
});
```

This uses underscore's [isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual), which may be a good default. Note that if `equals` does become available at some future date, [defaults](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) will prevent the patch from being applied.

I tested it with:

```js
var v = new ReactiveVar();

v.set({fancy: 'pantz'});

Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (v.equals({fancy: 'pants'})) {
    console.log('HORAY!');
  }
});

Meteor.setTimeout((function() {
  v.set({fancy: 'pants'});
}), 1000);
```

Note that unlike `Session.equals`, the dependency will be rerun after any change (rather than only when the equality condition is met).

Comment: But your `equals` method still causes redundant reruns, right? If `v` got the value `1`, and one uses `v.equals(5)` in an autorun, that autorun should only rerun when `v` changes it value to `5`. With your solution, it reruns as son as `v` changes to any other value, right? Is it hard to change it so it works like `ReactiveDict` (`Session`)?

Comment: You are correct - the code above will cause the computation to rerun after any change, rather than only when the equality condition is met. It may be possible to optimize the tracking for scalars, but not for objects, without also implementing an `equalsFunc`. Then again, if you only care about scalars it would probably be easier just to use a `ReactiveDict` with a constant key.

Comment: @DavidWeldon how to define template specific reactive vars?

Comment: @user1952811 I cover it in [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of equals() for ReactiveVar that will avoid redundant reruns in the same way that ReactiveDict.equals() does:

```js
ReactiveVar.prototype.equals  = function(comparisonValue) {
    var self = this;
    var isEqual = self.equalsFunc || ReactiveVar._isEqual;

    // don't bother storing dependencies if executing outside a computation
    if (!Tracker.active) {
        return isEqual(self.curValue, comparisonValue);
    }

    // make sure we have a place to put dependencies for each comparisonValue
    if (!_.has(self, "equalsDeps"))
        self.equalsDeps = {};

    var valueString = (comparisonValue === undefined) 
        ? "undefined" 
        : EJSON.stringify(comparisonValue);

    if (! _.has(self.equalsDeps, valueString))
        self.equalsDeps[valueString] = new ReactiveVar();

    // This gets run every time the variable value changes
    Tracker.autorun( function() {

        // If newEqualityValue is unchanged, nothing happens in the set(), and
        // nothing more needs to be calculated.  It's this that filters out 
        // the unnecessary reruns.
        var newEqualityValue = isEqual(self.get(), comparisonValue);
        self.equalsDeps[valueString].set(newEqualityValue);
    });

    Tracker.onInvalidate( function() {
        // Check if there are any remaining computations that depend on 
        // equalling this value. If not, remove the dependency to keep
        // from using memory for every value ever compared against.
        //
        // This needs to be done in an afterFlush because tracked 
        // dependents aren't updated till after onInvalidate callbacks 
        // are called.
        Tracker.afterFlush( function() {
            if (self.equalsDeps[valueString] && !self.equalsDeps[valueString].dep.hasDependents()) {
                delete self.equalsDeps[valueString];
            }
        });

    });

    // This get() returns the comparison calculated in the above autorun, and
    // invalidates the enclosing computation if that value changed (from true
    // to false, say). This triggers the necessary reruns.
    return self.equalsDeps[valueString].get();
}
```